# How to retrieve campaign budgets and adset bids in facebook marketing api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I can find in the docs how to set campaign budgets or adset bids ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/bidding/guides/campaign-budget-optimization ), but can't really find how you can retrieve those values - which is what I need. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group#Updating, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign#parameters-3 …?

Comment: @CBroe yeah, already found that myself, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what I needed was:

`AD_ACCOUNT_ID/adsets?fields=bid_amount`

and

`AD_ACCOUNT_ID/campaigns?fields=daily_budget`